# undefined local variable or method `image' for image-url in ERB/Coffee Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

There is the following code in "controllers.js.coffee.erb" file:

```
  $rootScope.icons = [
                    "<%= image-url('marker_1.png') %>", '/assets/marker_2.png',
                    '/assets/marker_3.png', '/assets/marker_4.png',
                    '/assets/marker_5.png', '/assets/marker_6.png',
                    '/assets/marker_7.png',
                 ]
```

But when I try to open a browser page I got the following error:

```
"undefined local variable or method `image' for #<#<Class:0x007fdb8e411d08>:0x007fdb8e1e1f88>
  (in /Users/marya/Rails/web_app/app/assets/javascripts/angular/modules/places/controllers.js.coffee.erb)"
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image-url is a helper method provided by sass-rails and you can use it in javascript and stylesheet files, but not in erb files. You should either use asset_path or use image-url outside of <%= %> so that it is not evaluated as ruby script.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass